# How to call a stored procedure to bind data to dropdownlist using Entity Framework Database First approach with three tier architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I call a stored procedure to bind data to a dropdownlist using the Entity Framework Database First approach with three tier architecture?

I created a business logic class in BusinessAccessLayer(project) and I am using the Entity Framework Database First approach. I added the reference to DataAccess layer to BusinessAccessLayer. How can I access the data from the stored procedure in the BusinessAccessLayer.

Below is my code:

## ASPX code in UI layer

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server">

    <asp:ListItem Selected="True">---->Please select<----</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Address</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Background</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Operations</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Groundwater</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Soil</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Vocs</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>SurfaceWater</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Regulatory/Legal</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

## BusinessAccessLayer

```
 ehsEntities db=new ehsEntities();
   //table name is tbl_Category
 public IList<tbl_Category> GetCategory()
   {
 //what is "Database" word below??
  var CategoryData =ehsEntities.Database.SqlQuery<T>("SP_GET_WaterReport");
   new Object[] { new SqlParameter(categoryID)}).ToList<T>();}
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (CommonManager objCommonController = new CommonManager())
            {
                objCommonController.LogException("CorporateManager: GetWaterReport - Problem in fetching EW report data", ex, HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"].ToString());
            }
        }
        return CategoryData;
```

Comment: First add the stored procedure to the Model. Then you can call the sp like `db.SP_GET_WaterReport(...)`

Comment: i have already done  it